# ¿Cómo enviar parametros en json con RESTRequest Delphi 10.3?

Tags: json, delphi-rio

Estoy tratando de hacer una inserción de un registro en un api rest, lo hago desde Delphi usando lo componentes RESTClient, puedo construir el json pero no sé como enviarlo!! hay mucha formas de construir el json pero igual no funciona. este es el el json que recibe la api:

```
{
    "Identity": "sfsfjifndifhdf24641",
    "DateEs": "2021-12-01",
    "DateEL": "2022-12-01",
    "License": 1251,
    "Marca": 1,
    "Software": 9,
    "CompanyName": "JEUS CORDOVA PRUYEBAS",
    "Phone": "26566",
    "Email": "CORDOVA@GMAIL.COM",
    "Document": "265665",
    "Address": "SUBA",
    "Active": true  
    
}
```

y este el código Delphi con lo que intento enviarlo:

```
var
  content : String;
begin
  //Crear la licencia
  RESTRequest2.Accept:='application/json';
  RESTRequest2.Resource:= 'CreateKey';
  content:='{'+
        '  "Identity": "sfsfjifndifhdf24641",'+
        '  "DateEs": "2021-12-01",'+
        '  "DateEL": "2022-12-01",'+
        '  "License": "1251",'+
        '  "Marca": "1",'+
        '  "Software": "9",'+
        '  "CompanyName": "JEUS CORDOVA PRUYEBAS",'+
        '  "Phone": "26566",'+
        '  "Email": "CORDOVA@GMAIL.COM",'+
        '  "Document": "1201642",'+
        '  "Address": "SUBA",'+
        '  "Active": "true",'+

        '}';
  //RESTRequest2.Params.AddItem('body',content,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY,[],ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
  RESTRequest2.AddParameter('Content-Type', 'application/json', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
  RESTRequest2.AddParameter('Accept', 'application/json', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
  RESTRequest2.Method:= rmPOST;
  RESTRequest2.Execute;
```

si ejecuto la linea comentada donde especifico el JSON entonces me da este error: Response content is not valid JSON

pero si la comento y ejecuto las otras dos dice igual que el anterior. En Postman solo puedo enviarla como JSON si uso el formulario entonces da un error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si debes enviar el contenido JSON en el body puedes utilizar directamente la propiedad `Body`.
[Propiedad Body de TRestRequest](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.Body)

Por ejemplo, puedes utilizar un código como este:

```
fStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenReadWrite) 
RESTRequest1.Body.Add(fStream, TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
```

También puedes encontrar más opciones [con diferentes parámetros](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.TBody.Add) para el método `Add`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probar y les cuento entonces cómo me fué! Agradesco mucho la ayuda que me han prestado porquye no solo me ha indicado el código que podría colocar sino también referencias, eso enriquece la enseñanza, me ayuda en mi crecimiento, nuevamente gracias!

Comment: Sí efectivamente funciona a la perfección, como había probado tantos códigos sin éxito, había desconfigurado los componentes pues en Acept: había colocado información del tipo y también había modificado otras propiedades, entonces coloqué nuevos componentes con parámetros por defecto y solo bastó esta línea: RESTRequest1.Body.Add(fStream, TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON);    en fStream coloqué la variable que contiene le json y listo!!! muchas gracias nuevamenet!!!

Comment: Creo que se puede marcar una pregunta/respuesta como solucionada, para que pueda servir a otros usuarios.